We cant change the color of old disabled date color in caldroid fragment
 @Override
            public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
 calendar.clearDisableDates();
  for(int i=0;i<disableDates.size();i++){
                    calendar.clearBackgroundDrawableForDate(disableDates.get(i));
                    calendar.setTextColorForDate(getResources().getColor(R.color.divider),disableDates.get(i));
                }
                calendar.refreshView();}


for onresume the disabled color showed for the past disabled date but the date was clickable. want to show normal date color. i tried refreshview() but the calendar not refreshed but in my fragment oncreateview its showed correctly.
